# Mermaid in docsify return [Object Promise]

Tags: promise, markdown, mermaid, docsify

Implement mermaid in docsify doc without success

Hello i'm trying to implement mermaid flowchart in my docsify project but my html return [Object Promise]

I try with differents version of mermaid but always without success.

Here my conf html

```html
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var num = 0;
      mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: false });
      window.$docsify = {
        name: "", // TODO: Update.
        auto2top: true,
        coverpage: true,
        loadSidebar: true,
        subMaxLevel: 2,
        themeColor: "#3170a7",
        markdown: {
          smartypants: false,
          renderer: {
            code: function (code, lang) {
              if (lang == "mermaid") {
                return `<div class="mermaid">${mermaid.render("mermaid-svg-" + num++, code)}</div>`;
              }
              return this.origin.code.apply(this, arguments);
            },
          },
        },
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

The result:

[image]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong and i'don't find many solutions. If someone here can helpe me :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve this by changing cdn version:

Use this one: //cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@9.4.3/dist/mermaid.min.js

But if someone as a solution to fix the [object promise] it will be better